# How can I read files from the hard drive in an old laptop that doesn't work?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an old hard drive from a laptop that doesn't power on anymore. I would like to see what old files are on the hard drive. It's a **Hitachi DK23FB-60**.

How can I hook this up to my current windows machine and access the hard drive?

Thanks for your time and appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to slave it. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+slave+hard+drive&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB779GB779&oq=how+to+slave+hard+drive&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2072j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You may need an IDE to USB or similar if your new machine doens't have any IDE slots free

Comment: Laptop doesn't work, or laptop works, but hard drive doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the drive from your laptop. It will vary in difficulty based on laptop type. Refer to the laptop manual if necessary.

Get an IDE to USB adapter ([some examples](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-google&sa=X&biw=412&bih=604&tbm=shop&noj=1&ei=lJ2FWqrlLaKB5wLYn4nIDw&q=ide+to+usb+adapter&oq=ide+to+usb+adapter&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0.203316.206544.0.206951.11.9.2.0.0.0.146.684.8j1.9.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.3.314...0i13k1.0.NjauyV98PCo))

Connect the adapter to the drive and then plug it into your computer.

Comment: You are skipping the most important detail that may not be too obvious by everyone: Learn how to remove the harddisk from the laptop. Sometimes it are just a few screws at the back, sometimes many screws have to be removed, laptop turned around, keyboard removed and under there, the harddrive can be removed.

Comment: You're right. I just assumed since he knew the model of the HD that it was already out. Besides, without knowing the type of laptop it's not really possible to make a generic answer for that

Comment: You can at least add to your answer: if you have not already taken out the harddrive, do so. Refer to the manual that came with your laptop on how to do so.